NFC Tag Reader Session HCE ISO 7816 tag
I'm trying to read an emulated HCE tag from another application, but I always get the same error in the sendCommand response:
-[NFCTagReaderSession _connectTag:error:]:744 Error Domain=NFCError Code=2 "Missing required entitlement" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing required entitlement} ERROR: Tag is not connected
This is my entitlements file:
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>TAG</string>
        <string>NDEF</string>
    </array>
</dict>

This is my info.plist:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

        <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
        <array>
            <string>remote-notification</string>
        </array>
        <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
        <array>
            <string>F00102030405</string>
        </array>

This is my code:
func startNFCSession() {
let pollingOptions: NFCTagReaderSession.PollingOption = \[.iso14443\]
nfcSession = NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption: pollingOptions, delegate: self, queue: nil)
nfcSession?.alertMessage = NSLocalizedString("Hold the device close to scan the ticket.", comment: "")
nfcSession?.begin()
}

func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
        
        if tags.count > 1 {
            session.alertMessage = NSLocalizedString("Multiple tags detected. Try again.", comment: "")
            session.restartPolling()
            return
        }
    
        guard let firstTag = tags.first else {
            session.invalidate(errorMessage: NSLocalizedString("No tags found", comment: ""))
            return
        }
        
        guard case let .iso7816(iso7816Tag) = firstTag else {
            session.invalidate(errorMessage: NSLocalizedString("Incompatible tag", comment: ""))
            return
        }
        
        session.connect(to: firstTag) { (error: Error?) in
            if let error = error {
                session.invalidate(errorMessage: String(format: NSLocalizedString("Connection error: %@", comment: ""), error.localizedDescription))
                return
            }
    
            let apduCommand = NFCISO7816APDU(
                instructionClass: 0x00,
                instructionCode: 0xA4,
                p1Parameter: 0x04,
                p2Parameter: 0x00,
                data: Data([0xF0, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05]),
                expectedResponseLength: -1
            )
            iso7816Tag.sendCommand(apdu: apduCommand) { (responseData, sw1, sw2, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    session.invalidate(errorMessage: String(format: NSLocalizedString("Error sending APDU: %@", comment: ""), error.localizedDescription))
                } else {
                    self.handleResponse(session: session, responseData: responseData, sw1: sw1, sw2: sw2)
                }
            }
        }
    
    }


As the communication with a HCE emulated NFC tag can be "tricky" it would be fine if you could give more informatio about that part. Most important is the Application Identifier (AID) that the HCE tag is working with. A reader application needs to match exactly with this AID, meaning your Reader application "calls" that specific AID and ONLY when it's the one of the HCE tag it will respond. Your reader app is using this <string>F00102030405</string> AID - is this the AID the HCE tag is using as well ?

@MichaelFehr thanks for your comment. It is correct, F00102030405 is used in the com.apple.developer.nfc.hce.iso7816.select-identifier-prefixes array of the HCE app and the same AID is used in the com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers array of the reader app.

Your apduCommand = NFCISO7816APDU is using this data for connection: data: Data([0xF0, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05]), - I'm missing the 00 after F0, so the complete sequence should be data: Data([0xF0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05]),. Hope that helps.

Thans @MichaelFehr but my AID is F0 01 02 03 04 05, then I think data may be [0xF0, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05]. In any case with 0xF0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, same result...

Your "apduCommand = NFCISO7816APDU" is missing the LE = length field.

It's set to -1: "Response data length (Le) in bytes. Valid range is from 1 to 65536 inclusively; -1 means no response data field is expected.  Use 256 if you want to send '00' as the short Le field assuming the data field is less than 256 bytes.  Use 65536 if you want to send '0000' as the extended Le field."

Sorry for misnaming a parameter - I meant the LC parameter. An APDU for a wraped comand  is usually of this structure: instruction class - instruction code - p1 - p2 - LC - data - LE. You don't give the LC = Length of data in the APDU.
